# Copy worksheet over to another workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to export a worksheet from Workbook A to another Workbook B which I need Excel to prompt me to choose. I am getting an error "Type Mismatch". Alternatively, I can export to an entirely new Workbook as well.

```
Sub savefile()
Worksheets("Test").Activate

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim filter As String
Dim linkf As Variant
Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook

Set targetWorkbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook
caption = "Please Select an output file "
linkf = Application.GetOpenFilename(filter, , caption)

If linkf = False Then Exit Sub

Set wb = Workbooks.Open(linkf)
targetWorkbook.Sheets("Test").Copy After:=Workbooks(wb).Sheets("Sample")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the following line

```
targetWorkbook.Sheets("Test").Copy After:=Workbooks(wb).Sheets("Sample")
```

to

```
targetWorkbook.Sheets("Test").Copy After:=wb.Sheets("Sample")
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your last line with this:
targetWorkbook.Sheets("Test").Copy After:=wb.Sheets("Sample")

Make sure that you have a worksheet called "Sample" in the second workbook